# Configuration Failed to import bean definitions from relative location

Tags: spring

My folder structure is:

```
src/main---java
           resources/META-INF/Spring-context/application.xml
           webapp/WEB-INF--web.xml
                           despatcher-servlet.xml
```

from `webapp/WEB-INF/despatcher-servlet` i am trying to import application.xml like

```
<import resource="classes/META-INF/spring-context/application.xml"/>
```

getting exception like
Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location `[classes/META-INF/springcontext/application.xml]`
Can any one help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your configuration file is in classpath so you have to use `classpath:` prefix also remove classes from the path.
Your settings will be:

```
classpath:META-INF/springcontext/application.xml
```